# Ways to find if a server is infected by a bot

Tags: ip, blacklist

Seeking a method to discover if & where any malicious bot could be running on my Ubuntu desktop and server...and how to safely remove any.

Comment: How do you know your IP is blacklisted? Where are you getting that info?

Comment: check incomming and outgoing traffic.

Answer (score 0):

The chances of you being infected by a malware are very low but it's better to be safe. Please take a look at the official help guide of Ubuntu **[here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus)**.

It lists out various anti-virus programs which can possibly detect if your system is running any instance of a virus/malware/spyware etc.